# set right Margins with setLayoutParams doesn't change my constraintLayout

Tags: android, layout, margin, android-constraintlayout

I have this constraint layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="Overdraw">

  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/popover"
      style="@style/popover_style"
      android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottom_margin"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/side_margin"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/side_margin"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0">
  </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to change the positioning of my `popover` view via code.

sometimes to center horizontally.

Some other times to make its left margins fix sized.

illustration:
[image]

I have tried this code, but the view always seems to be centered horizontally.

What am I missing?

```
  private void setupPopoverPosition() {
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(rootView);
    int bottomMargin =
        getContext()
            .getResources()

            //some code

    constraintSet.applyTo(rootView);
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
        (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) popover.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.topMargin = topMargin;
    layoutParams.bottomMargin = bottomMargin;


        layoutParams.rightMargin = popoverEndMargin;
        popover.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


    popover.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    popover.requestLayout();
  }
```

Comment: Try to add a constraint Top to your View, also(another solution) have you tried to change the horizontal bias ?

Comment: I have a top constraint, but omitted here to make the question simpler. why does it change?

Comment: @Benda i had a similar issue, connecting the View with all constraint has helped, also try changing the margin with ConstraintSet there is a method setMargin()